# Map a BST module to lists

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to use the `Map.Make` functor to map a BST implementation to lists. I managed to create the map but I don't know how to add a general tree to the module with the mappings. In the code below I mapped the empty tree (`Leaf`) to the empty list `[]`. I would like to map any tree with type `Node of int * tree * tree` to a list containing the values in the nodes `[v1;...;vn]`. The last line has an example of what I would like to do for a tree with one node with value 2.

```
let m = 
  let open TreeMap in
  empty
  |> add Leaf [] 
  |> add (Node (2, Leaf, Leaf)) [2]
```

Thanks,
Federico

Comment: TreeMap is created by
 module TreeMap Map.Make(TreeKey)

Answer (score 0):

A map is a finite data structure, there is an infinite number of trees. You cannot store all pairs of trees and lists into a map.

You can fold a tree into a list with a recursive function.

Comment: OK, thank you. I just wanted to understand the utility of the Map module. I thought you could write an abstract type on the modules with the mappings and then use a function that gives you the mapping you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you were asked to "map" a BST to a list, I'm not really sure you were meant to use a map data structure, rather than just *mapping* the two with a function.

Something like the following.

```
# type 'a tree = Leaf of 'a | Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree;;
type 'a tree = Leaf of 'a | Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree
# let rec tree_to_list = function
    | Leaf v -> [v]
    | Node (v, l, r) -> tree_to_list l @ [v] @ tree_to_list r;;
val tree_to_list : 'a tree -> 'a list = <fun>
# tree_to_list (Node (4, Leaf 3, Node (6, Leaf 5, Leaf 7)));;
- : int list = [3; 4; 5; 6; 7]
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess what I wanted to know is if there is a way to use the Map.Make functor more generally than to just write a bunch of examples of mappings like I did above.